# Why can't files introduced by require.context() be dynamically updated in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, static, markdown

I am building an **static markdown blog website** using Vue3,and I am using **require.context()** to load markdown files.

This is the project structure,and I load files from `static/posts`.

```
├── dist
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── static
│   │       └── posts
│   │           ├── dev-first-vue3-todolist.md
│   │           ├── dev-fix-missing-xcrun.md
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── main.js
├── static
│   └── posts
│       ├── dev-first-vue3-todolist.md
│       ├── dev-fix-missing-xcrun.md
└── vue.config.js
```

Here's  how I load these markdown files.

```
let context = require.context("../static/posts", true, /\.md$/, "sync");
let keys = context.keys();

// the markdown file list
const postRawList = [];

keys.forEach((key) => {
  const raw = context(key).default;
  postRawList.push(raw);
});
```

It worked well. I can read `postRawList`  from `static/posts` and render them by markdown parser.

The point is, I want my blog website static, so when I build this Vue app I use `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy these markdown files from `static/posts` to `dist/assets/static/posts` and it worked well.

```
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/posts"),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/assets/static/posts"),
          },
        ],
      })
    );
```

I want to manage my markdown posts only by adding or deleting markdown files in `dist/assets/static/posts`.

**But after I changing the markdown files in `dist/assets/static/posts`(like delete `dev-first-vue3-todolist.md`) ,the  markdown object list(`postRawList`) doesn't be updated.**

The markdown list is the same as the markdown list in `static/posts` , and no matter how I change files in this 2 posts folder,it does't be updated.

I guess it is caused by "require cache", and I had tried to delete cache after changing the files, but it did't work.

```
delete require.cache[context.id];
```

So I want to know **why the file objects not be updated after I built the app and  change the files in markdown directory(loaded by require.context()).**

This is my first time asking questions on stackoverflow,and I feel sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: This isn't how Webpack works. It already bundled the content of .md files into .js. You can copy them to dist/ but these files will be irrelevant. You should rebuild the app when the content is changed, this is how SSG works.

Comment: Thank you！I guess I need to use some SSG framework like nuxt.js to rebuild my blog app…